# Analyticity of function $g(w)$ given that $g(w)=f(z)$ and $f(z)$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose you have a function $f(z)$ which is entire on the complex $z$ plane. Now consider variable $w=z^2$ and define a function $g(w)$ on the $w$ plane such that $g(w)=f(z)$. What if anything can be said about the analyticity of $g(w)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, you can't just "define" $g$ by $g(z^2)=f(z)$. In general there may be no such function $g$.

> > **Related Fact.** Given an entire function $f$ there exists an entire function $g$ with $g(z^2)=f(z)$ if and only if $f$ is even.

Proof: It's clear that if $g(z^2)=f(z)$ then $f(-z)=f(z)$. For the converse we wimp out and take advantage of the fact that these are *entire* functions: If $f$ is an even entire function then $$f(z)=\sum c_nz^{2n},$$so you can let $g(z)=\sum c_nz^n$.

Of course that really doesn't answer the question. I was surprised to find the answer is "$g$ is entire"; I thought that we'd need to assume in addition at least that $g$ is continuous. But:

> > Suppose $f$ is an entire function, $g:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$, and $g(z^2)=f(z)$. Then $g$ is entire.

Proof: Choose a function $\phi:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ with $\phi(w)^2=w$. (Of course $\phi$ is not continuous, turns out that doesn't matter.) As above $f$ is even, so $f(z)=\sum c_nz^{2n}$. Now $$g(w)=g(\phi(w)^2)
=f(\phi(w))=\sum c_n(\phi(w))^{2n}=\sum c_nw^n.$$

Answer (score 1):

This function is not well defined. Do you define $g(1)$ as $f(1)$ or $f(-1)$? ($(1^{2}=(-1)^{2}=1$).

Comment: You are right. Ok, what if you restrict the domain on $z$ to $\Re z > 0$? Does that improve things?

Comment: No, $g$ is still not analytic (even for the function $f(z)=z)$. You have to restrict the domain of $g$, i.e. you have to restrict $w$ itself to get an analytic function. For example you can say that $g$ is analytic on $Re(w) >0$.

Comment: How does that resolve the ambiguity which you pointed out?

Comment: Well, it can be shown that there is an analytic branch of squre root on the right half plane. I was assuming this when I made my previous comment.